# how to solve image slices rotation bug?

Tags: wpf, silverlight, xaml, winrt-xaml

I have the two slices of one image which is a ring, the slices are vertical cut of image, so 
i have taken grid then,i created two equal columns,then i placed left slice into left column and right slice into right cloumn.After that i started Rotating

At '0','90','180','360' angle image looks like below[image]

it is look like ok

but at rest of angles, small split is visible while rotation like below
[image]

can anybody help me, what i can do for perfect rotation at all other angles?

Btw i am doing winrt application !

Comment: Are you literally just rotating a ring? Do you have your Fill set to UniformToFill?

Comment: i rotating the grid container which is having the ring, and also i tried with all possibilities strech,fill,uniformtofill.

Comment: If all you're doing is rotating a ring, I was going to suggest just using a solid Path object instead of images. However if it's two separate images, I'll have to test a thing or two before I would want to give it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

To me, the answer is overlap. But, take advantage that the images match at 0 and use a `RotateTransform` to spin your ring. Like this:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RenderTransform>
        <RotateTransform Angle="90" />
    </Grid.RenderTransform>
    <Image Source="ms-appx:///images/Arc1.jpg" />
    <Image Source="ms-appx:///images/Arc2.jpg" />
</Grid>
```

Best of luck!